# What are the list of bugs you got, when you were developing an Android Application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

What are the list of bugs you got, when you were developing an Android Application?

*There are some known bugs and some unknown(they not described in documentation).*

For example

*Known Bug :*

Several devices by several manufacturers are affected by the ANDROID_ID bug in 2.2.
As far as I've been able to determine, all affected devices have the same ANDROID_ID, which is9774d56d682e549c. Which is also the same device id reported by the emulator.

*Unknown Bug :*

`telephonyManager.getLine1Number()` : Used to read phone number, but some devices(not any specific) returns null, even though they having Phone application.

*So I think there should be a list of bugs, where at the time of development, we can keep those in mind.*

*There could be some API wise bugs. Can you list them please?*

Answer (score 2):

Strange thing i could remember at the moment is if You use a RelativeLayout inside tabs for Android 2.1 it will give some decoreView error , while works fine with otherLayouts . so test your app on 2.1 if have TabWidget

Answer (score 2):

A known bug, but will show at compile time with error

> R cannot be resolved

when we use android SDK with eclipse..Eclipse sometimes erronously add

```
import android.R
```

which will break the make process during compilation..google documented against this bug in [this](http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html) page.

> Note: Eclipse sometimes likes to add an import android.R statement at
>   the top of your files that use resources, especially when you ask
>   eclipse to sort or otherwise manage imports. This will cause your make
>   to break. Look out for these erroneous import statements and delete
>   them.